# NGINX infinite loop when I try to redirect http to https

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I'm moving my entire website from http to https
Since I have a few domains, I need to redirect then to the https version of my website.

The problem is that when I try to redirect the original domain from http to https, the nginx gives me a infinite loop.

Can you guys help me?

Here it is my config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com.br domain.com.br w.domain.com.br  ww.domain.com.br wwww.domain.com.br domain1.com.br www.domain1.com.br domain.com www.domain.com domain.net.br www.domain.net.br;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  domain.com.br w.domain.com.br  ww.domain.com.br wwww.domain.com.br domain1.com.br www.domain1.com.br domain.com www.domain.com domain.net.br www.domain.net.br;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/ssl/myserver.key;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/ssl/myserver.key;
    #ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    #ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    server_name  www.domain.com.br;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html2;


    location / {   
        index  index.php;
        if ($request_filename !~* \.(php|gif|html|jpe?g|png|ico|js|css|flv|swf|pdf|xml)$ ) { rewrite ^ /index.php; }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {        
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.socket;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second server entry is creating the infinite loop. It includes a return 301 to the same site on the https(443) port

Try this answer for sub domain redirects:
https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

Comment: i can't understand why the second is creating a infinite loop

The second server entry does not match the address: www.domain.com.br only the third one.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Because the server name you are redirecting to is in the "server names"

Comment: You are also listing the "catch all" first.

Comment: Do you mean that this

server_name  domain.com.br

Catches every subdomain like www.domain.com.br ?